# ViewPager: override getItemPosition(Object object) method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

On android developer blog i've read this:

> If you’re trying to replace Views in your ViewPager, it isn’t enough just to change the data set behind the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged(). You also need to ensure that you’ve correctly implemented getItemPosition(Object object) and return POSITION_NONE for items that have changed and return POSITION_UNCHANGED or the actual position for items that haven’t changed.

what does it mean "replave Views"? so if i have for example a Fragment of ViewPager contains an ArrayAdapter and i append new data, i need to call inside fragment notifyDataSetChanged() and catch it inside ViewPager with getItemPosition()?
what's wrong if i don't do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify the dataset of a viewpager it also wants to know if the fragments or views are in the same order as before. You do that overriding the getItemPosition(obj).

If you don't do this the viewpager won't know the new order of views, so it could mess up.

Comment: in my use case, Fragments stay always in the same position and order. It changes only the data inside it. So i don't need to call that two methods?

Comment: I have your exact same situation and didn't override the method, everything works correctly. You need that only if you want to change the fragments' order.